# Unity3D InputSystem works in editor but not in Build

Tags: unity, input

I am trying to move a camera around with controller input using the new Unity Input System package (Ver. 1.2.0) and everything is working great in the editor. However, as soon as I build the project and run it, my inputs don't do anything. Here is my camera controller script which uses my Input Actions map (below it) to move around my camera object (below that).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{

    PlayerControls controls;
    Vector2 move;
    Vector2 rotate;


    private void Awake()
    {
        controls = new PlayerControls();
        controls.Gameplay.Move.performed += ctx => move = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        controls.Gameplay.Camera.performed += ctx => rotate = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();

        controls.Gameplay.Move.canceled += ctx => move = Vector2.zero;
        controls.Gameplay.Camera.canceled += ctx => rotate = Vector2.zero;

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Vector2 m = new Vector2(move.x, 0f) * 10 * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(m, Space.Self);

        float f = move.y * 10 * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(transform.forward * f, Space.World);

        Vector2 r = new Vector2(-rotate.y, rotate.x) * 75 * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Rotate(r, Space.Self);
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        controls.Gameplay.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        controls.Gameplay.Disable();
    }
}
```

[image: Input Actions map]

[image]

Similar topics mention version issues, but those are all for much older versions of the plugin. Has anyone come across this issue or sees anything wrong with my set up?

Comment: What platform do you build for? When PC: When you add some additional bindings for keyboard keys, do those work?

Comment: Im building for Windows x86_64, when i add a keyboard keybind it still doesn't trigger any actions to occur in the build version

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems I had some compatibility issue as remaking everything in a clean project fixed the issue.